# Use .htaccess to convert user ID's to usernames?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to use .htaccess to convert the urls that link to profile pages from an ID number to a name. For example, on Facebook, if you were to go to:

```
https://facebook.com/profile.php?id=4
```

It would take you to Mark Zuckerberg's profile page. However, you can also simply go to:

```
https://facebook.com/zuck
```

...which is more user friendly and easier to remember. How can I use htaccess to convert an id number to a username? Do I need to send it to a php script to process and send back the name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't specifically with `.htaccess` because you'd need to grab the username for that ID from your database, however you CAN use PHP to do so. 
In your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Then, you can check something like this in `profile.php`:

```
if(isset($_GET['user'])){
    if(is_numeric($_GET['user'])){ //Check if the input is all numeric
        //Grab the username from database
        //Redirect user to site.com/user/$username
    }
}
```

More info on PHP's `is_numeric()` function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

You might want to also check if the user's username is completely numeric, to avoid constantly redirecting the user. If you make sure users don't have all numeric usernames, you'll be fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as an `.htaccess` can't access a storage layer, you have to use a `PHP` script which transform your `ID` to a `username` and then do the redirect.